# Flashligth LED cannot be turned on in Galaxy S2 (JB)

Tags: camera, galaxy, led, flashlight, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm working on an app which will turn on the flash light LED of the handsets.  The code is general:

```
cam = Camera.open();
cam.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
camPara = cam.getParameters();
camPara.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(camPara);
cam.startPreview();
```

This code works properly in many handsets, but the flashlight LED will not turn on in Galaxy S2 (4.1.2).

Did any body meet the similar problem or has experience in why the Galaxy S2 has such problem in the api??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source for this simple Android flashlight app that I published: [Simple Android Flashlight App](http://www.neilson.co.za/?p=117)

Comment: I noticed that I didn't need the cam.startPreview() part when i ran it on my old S2... I did need it on the S4 though.